# Runs cucumber feature file locally

Tags: cucumber, ui-automation, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I have the framework installed in VM, written in Java + selenium and I used maven for dependency. I would like to let people using cucumber as a client and execute there features-scenarios locally. What are the options for this case?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please be a bit more precise what you want to achieve and what you already tried.

Comment: Sure, The framework is installed in virtual machine and I have about 10 Manuel users want's to use cucumber and execute the features file from there own machine. Is that possible ?

Comment: Can they clone the project and run them from either the [command line](https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#running-cucumber) or their [IDE](https://docs.cucumber.io/tools/general/). Why does it have to be inside a VM?